# Build failed for task: apptransformClasseswithJarMergingForDebug

Tags: react-native, gradle, react-native-firebase

My build failed while importing RNFirebase library in the project
[snap source here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5mog3.png)

This is my gradle

```
dependencies {
compile(project(':react-native-firebase')) {
    transitive = false
}
compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"
compile project(':react-native-google-signin')
compile project(':react-native-fbsdk')
compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1"
compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
compile(project(":react-native-google-signin")){         
    exclude group: "com.google.android.gms" // very important
}
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.6.0"
compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.6.0"
compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.6.0"
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You are importing `react-native-google-signin` twice.

Remove the first entry: `compile project(':react-native-google-signin')` and leave:

```
compile(project(":react-native-google-signin")){         
    exclude group: "com.google.android.gms" // very important
}
```